# How does Perl parse print " " . ($x, $y) ."\n"?

Tags: perl

I know from Learning Perl, 6th Ed. (ISBN: 978-1-449-30358-7) p.58 that `($x, $y) = "something", "new";` is a list context. So why does the following code print " bee"? Please explain how does the code parsed.

```
$dina = bobba;
$ba = bee;
print " " . ($dina, $ba)."\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concatenation operator `.` imposes scalar context on the list created by the comma operator, so it returns its last member.

Comment: So why it doesn't return the length of that list, but its last member? I still don't understand the whole proccess.

Comment: @VitaliPom: Arrays return their length in scalar contexts, lists return their last members.

Comment: That's actually the comma operator in scalar context, which is different than a list.

Comment: @brian d foy, No, it's not the least bit different. It's the same N-ary op in both scalar and list context. The comma operator and the list operator are the same operator. You can see this by using `perl -MO=Concise`

Answer (score 4):

The most relevant documentation quote is this paragraph from perlop(1):

```
Comma Operator
    Binary "," is the comma operator.  In scalar context it evaluates its
    left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right
    argument and returns that value.  This is just like C's comma operator.
```

Answer (score 2):

"`($x, $y) = ("something", "new");` is a list context." makes no sense. (Added the missing parenthesis to avoid going off-topic.)

First, something is *evaluated in* list context.

Second, there's no way to know in which context that expression will be evaluated from what you posted, but chances are it's evaluated in *void* context.

You are probably referring to the sub expressions `($x, $y)` and `("something", "new")`. They are evaluated indeed evaluated in list context, and that's because the list assignment operator evaluates its operands in list context.

In your code, `($x, $y)` is the operand of a concatenation operator (`.`). The concatenation operator combines two strings, so it expects strings as operands. Strings being scalars, the concatenation operator evaluates its operands in scalar context.

---

In scalar context,

```
$x, $y
```

is about the same as

```
do { $x; $y }
```

(without the additional scope). Each item of the list is evaluated in turn in void or scalar context, and the whole evaluates to what the last item in the list returned.

```
>perl -E"sub f { say 'f'; 3 } sub g { say 'g'; 4 } say ':'.(f,g);"
f
g
:4
```